# FMod and Frac material functions cause seam in texture

Tags: unreal-engine4

Is there any way to get rid of the interpolation seam caused by using Frac or FMod? Coming from writing actual fragment shaders, I find it odd that this seam even exists (why is interpolation happening in the pixel sampling?)

Example, say we have this super simple texture

[image: Simple Texture]

And we want the top right corner to loop instead of the whole texture, something that's easy to accomplish with an FMod.

[image: Artifact]

As you can see, an artifact is now present from when the UV jumps from 0.25 to 0 and I'm not sure why. Is there a way I can disable this interpolation? With the power of MSPaint, here's what I expected to see:

[image: Artifact removed]

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to select only a left top corner and repeating it instead of having single image and use UV tiling? If you are using original texture as spritesheet, why not use it correctly? (https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Paper2D/Sprites/ )

Comment: Thanks for the link, but you're looking into the example a bit too far. I made that example to show the issue I'm talking about in its simplest form. My actual use case is far more nontrivial but is being hampered by the artifacts caused by fmod and frac -- basically anything that causes a hard seam of uvs between two nearby fragments will cause it to do a weird interpolation artifact on the boundary between them.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an okay temporary solution. If you disable mip-mapping (via the properties on the texture themselves) then the artifacts disappear. Would love to have another answer that describes how to do this while maintaining mipmaps.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this without disabling mipmaps is to explicitly derive the mip level instead of automatically generating them.
There is a setting in the texture sampler to do this. The sampler will now show an input for DDX and DDY.

Then, you can take an unaltered Texture Coordinate Node, and plug it into a DDX and DDY node, and then plug those into the corresponding sockets of the sampler.

The reason this happens is that mips are calculated based on the rate of change in the UV coordinates. When you alter UVs with math functions, the rate of change may become non-linear and cause the engine to think that a large distance has been spanned in UV space over a short amount of screen space.
This usually indicates the object is far away, so it will shade those pixels with the lowest quality mip map (which is often just one super blurry pixel), causing a seam against the high quality mip level being used on adjacent pixels.
Explicitly deriving the mips allows you to override the calculation using a second one. The unaltered tex coords will offer nice linear derivatives with no sudden jumps in mip level.